# Programmatically submitting to .do file

Tags: http-post

I'm hoping somebody might know the answer to this issue.  I'm writing an app that has to submit requests to a secure web page, which itself is the action for a secure web form page (not to state the obvious, but basically I'm trying to submit the information which would be filled out on the inital form, and submit it to the page specified in the form's "action"). The "action" URL which I have to submit to ends with a ".do" extension, which I understand specifies a dynamically built page in JAVA.

My problem is that I don't get anything back when I do the submission.  Here is the code I'm using (VB.Net, targeting version 4.0):

```
Dim PostValues As New NameValueCollection()
Dim RespString As String
Dim RespBytes() As Byte

' URL below is "action" for web form at https://www.deadiversion.usdoj.gov/webforms/validateLogin.jsp
Dim URL As String = "https://www.deadiversion.usdoj.gov/webforms/validateLogin.do"
' These POST values are obtained by examing the source code for the web form ".jsp" page, looking for "input" tags
PostValues.Add("submit", "")
PostValues.Add("deaNum", "--dea number value for our company--")
PostValues.Add("lname", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("boca pharmacal inc"))
PostValues.Add("ssn", "")
PostValues.Add("taxid", "--tax id value for our company--")
PostValues.Add("buttons.next", "Login")

Dim client As New WebClient()
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
client.UseDefaultCredentials = True
RespBytes = client.UploadValues(URL, "POST", PostValues)
RespString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(RespBytes)
```

When I run this code, RespBytes has a length of 0, and then RespString is simply an empty string. By contrast, if I experimentally substitute the URL ending in ".jsp" referred to in the comment above, I get back a response, no problem, so I don't think it has anything to do with the fact that it's an "https" URL.

I also experimentally took the ".do" URL, pasted it into my browser, and then tried to directly web browse to it.  In that case it sent back an empty page, just as it sent back nothing when I tried it programmatically, which would seem to indicate that for some reason it doesn't see the values I try to send via POST.

Does this have something to do with the fact that the URL ends with ".do"?  Is there something about submitting to such a URL that requires I do something special when submitting?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet directly off of Microsoft's website:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Namespace Examples.System.Net
    Public Class WebRequestPostExample

        Public Shared Sub Main()
            ' Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com/PostAccepter.aspx ")
            ' Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST"
            ' Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            Dim postData As String = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server."
            Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
            ' Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            ' Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
            ' Get the request stream.
            Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            ' Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
            ' Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close()
            ' Get the response.
            Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            ' Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
            ' Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
            ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
            ' Read the content.
            Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
            ' Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
            ' Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close()
            dataStream.Close()
            response.Close()
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

You can find the code at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-27